# PHP Time Difference

Tags: php, time

I have 2 dates in mysql: 

2018-07-13 13:00:00 - data
2018-07-14 16:01:00 - godzina

```
$timestamp1 = strtotime($data['data']);<br>
$timestamp2 = strtotime($data['godzina']);<br>
$time_difference = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1; 
$time_total = ($time_difference/3600);

echo "td".$time_total."/td";
```

Now it returns: `27.016666666667`

How to change it to: `27:01` in table?

Comment: use `number_format($time_total,2)`

Comment: no table - should be echo

Comment: So you want to make an html table and echo in it? For a start you need html tags, those tds should be `<td></td>`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `DateTime->diff` method to get the interval between those 2 dates:

```
$date1 = '2018-07-13 13:00:00';
$date2 = '2018-07-14 16:01:00';

$interval = (new DateTime($date2))->diff(new DateTime($date1));
$totalHours = $interval->days * 24 + $interval->h;

echo sprintf("%02d", $totalHours) . ':' . sprintf("%02d", $interval->i);
```